# Using of Threading.Sleep(1000); in C# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, thread-sleep

I'm making a quiz in unity. I want for an audio to play when clicking on the right answer. Although the line code of **playing the audio is before that of thread.Sleep()**, when playing the quiz, it **sleeps before enabling the audio!!** I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        checkAnswer();
    }
    public void checkAnswer()
    {
        if (Correct == true)
        {
            audioo = this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            audioo.enabled = true;
            Thread.Sleep(5000); 
            NextQuiz.SetActive(true);
            CurrentQuiz.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that unity is playing the audio after it stops sleeping? In which case why not simply use coroutines? Something like:

```
public void OnMouseDown(){
     {
           CheckAnswer();
     }
     public void CheckAnswer();
     {
        if (Correct == true)
        {
            audioo = this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            StartCoroutine(PlaySound(audioo));
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

IEnumerator PlaySound(AudioSource sound)
{
    //Play the sound here, then load up the next question.
    audioo.enabled = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    NextQuiz.SetActive(true);
    CurrentQuiz.SetActive(false);
}
```

Additionally, you can also replace constantly deactivating and reactivating the audio source on your object, by simply creating 2 AudioClip variables and assigning a correct sound to one, as well as an incorrect sound to the other, then using audioo.Play(clipName) in order to play the appropriate one, like so:

```
public AudioClip correctSound;
public AudioClip incorrectSound;

public void OnMouseDown(){
     {
           CheckAnswer();
     }
     public void CheckAnswer();
     {
        if (Correct == true)
        {
            audioo = this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            StartCoroutine(PlaySound(audioo, correctSound));
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

IEnumerator PlaySound(AudioSource audioSource, AudioClip audioClip)
{
    //Play the sound here, then load up the next question.
    audioSource.Play(audioClip);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    NextQuiz.SetActive(true);
    CurrentQuiz.SetActive(false);
}
```

Try something like that

Answer (score 1):

Audio playing happens on the main thread (Unity is mostly single-threaded) and your code makes current (currently main) thread to sleep, therefore audio doesn't get played until thread awakes from sleep.

To solve this, you might want to consider using [Unity coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Start the coroutine which would `yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);` and then start next quiz.